# mysql syntax in mariadb version 10.5.10

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Hello can i get some help on the below syntax error?

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 8167: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN `numMonth` INT(1)
) BEGIN 
SET 
  @strKey = ' WHERE `cd`.`KEY` = \'DELM\''...' at line 1
```

here is the sql code for that error

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `AA_SET_NUMBER`;

DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE DEFINER = `apple` @`%` PROCEDURE `AA_SET_NUMBER`(IN `numMonth` INT(1)) 
BEGIN 
    SET @strKey = ' WHERE `cd`.`KEY` = \'DELM\'';
    IF numMonth IS NULL THEN 
        SET @strMonth = ' AND MONTH(`c`.`CREATED_ON`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())';
    ELSE 
        SET @strMonth = CONCAT(' AND MONTH(`c`.`CREATED_ON`) = \'', 
    numMonth, '\' ');
    END IF;
```

Comment: Do you have an END to go with the BEGIN?

Comment: @RiggsFolly The error message complains about the parameter list.

Comment: It doesn't look like this is the whole procedure. It's apparently creating dynamic SQL which will later be executed with `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

Comment: Hello everyone, Yes it does have the END to the BEGIN. and i also see the ```PREPARE``` and ```EXECUTE``` in the script. its pretty long script to be pasted in this page, thats the reason i only posted the error and the lines of it.

Comment: If you show us PSEUDO code we can only give PSEUDO answers. I realise that if you really have `at line 8167` that many lines its difficult, but

Comment: This lines i pasted are from line 8160-8200

Comment: Works for me in 10.5.12 - https://paste.debian.net/1212780/

Comment: i see the same error even in 10.5.12